# Image not appearing on AJAX Rating on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am currently developing a page where users can rate products with the usage of AJAX Rating. The control works fine, users are able to rate products, however the images showing the rating does not appear.

This page is created with the use of a Master Page and the inclusion of a CSS Sheet stored elsewhere.

Below is the following CSS involved:-

```
<style type="text/css">
    .StarRating{
        font-size: 0pt;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        cursor:pointer;
        display: block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;}

    .FilledStars{
        background-image:url("css/images/star.png");
         width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .WaitingStars{
        background-image:url("css/images/wait.png");
         width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .EmptyStars{
        background-image:url("css/images/empty.png");
         width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }

</style>
```

And below is code for displaying the Rating:-

```
<tr>
        <td>Select Rating:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:scriptmanager ID="s1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
            <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1"  AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"
                        StarCssClass="StarRating"
                        FilledStarCssClass="FilledStars"
                        EmptyStarCssClass="EmptyStars"
                        WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStars"
                        MaxRating="5"
                        CurrentRating="1"
                        style="float: left;"
                        >

                    </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:updatepanel>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try to change your images path   "css/images/wait.png" to "/css/images/wait.png" or "~/css/images/wait.png" ?

Comment: yes, however its still not working

Comment: CSS `url(...` is relative to `.css` file. Check your folder structure